# For edittext, Is it possible to use InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and show only a numpad but allow letters?

Tags: android-edittext, android-inputtype

Is it possible to display only a number pad like w/ InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER but accept letters and hyphens too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the edittext's key listener did the trick.
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.-abc......etc));